# Odd error in expand.grid()

Tags: r

I've created and evaluated a call to `expand.grid` by using  `eval(parse(...))`.

In short:

```
len <- 36
Text <- paste("pos <- expand.grid(",
  paste(rep("c(TRUE,FALSE)", len), collapse=","), ")", sep="")
eval(parse(text = Text))
```

Gives me

```
Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : 
invalid 'times' value
In addition: Warning message:
In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

as opposed to `len` number of combinations of `TRUE`/`FALSE` in the variable `pos`.

I am overlooking something simple, or maybe not...?

Comment: `foo` is too long. 2^36 is rather big. Possibly you uncovered a bug that appears in `expand.grid` with very long vectors, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `eval` or `parse`.  The error is in `expand.grid`.

Comment: I can get up to around 2^24, but beyond that I run into trouble.

Comment: Ah. A more graceful error would be nice. Thanks chaps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this has nothing to do with `eval` or `parse`.  The error is in `expand.grid`.  The problem is that R's maximum vector length is 2^31-1 and `rep.int` is trying to create a 2^36 length vector.

Comment: What is an alternative to `expand.grid` if I absolutely had to create such a long vector?

Comment: Something like: x <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2^36)... except that on most desktop machines you'd run into memory problems. If you really need a vector this long, try breaking it into chunks if that works for your use of the values in the vector.