# Create all combinations of items with many items

Tags: r, vector, combn

I want to have the possible combinations for a variety of items. Think of participants bringing one of three items to an event, and I want to know the different combinations (order of participants don't matter). For instance,

```
items <- rep(list(1:3), 5)
combinations <- expand.grid(items)
head(combinations)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1    1    1    1    1    1
2    2    1    1    1    1
3    3    1    1    1    1
4    1    2    1    1    1
5    2    2    1    1    1
6    3    2    1    1    1
```

gives me the desired dataframe of combinations for 5 participants.

Now, imagine I have 50 participants. Then:

```
items <- rep(list(1:3), 50)
combinations <- expand.grid(items)
Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : 
  invalid 'times' value
In addition: Warning message:
In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

The problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655441/odd-error-in-expand-grid) and arises due to limits on the size of vectors in R. So, it seems `expand.grid` is out of question.

Are there any alternatives to get my desired output in `R`? As far as I know, long vectors are supported in `R` since version 3.0, so I am a bit surprised to see that they are not yet implemented. Any pointers to alternatives are highly appreciated!

Comment: One approach you might consider is avoid generating all combinations at once and only when they are needed. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143323/pythons-xrange-alternative-for-r-or-how-to-loop-over-large-dataset-lazilly) a QA on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 50 participants you create a dataframe with 3^50= 7.17898e+23 rows. Which is impossible to save in your memory. So I think it is a scaling problem.